# Using Account Auth to verify if logged in yet

Tags: python, django, authentication, view

I have a small view:

```
def AccountHome(request):

    return render(request, 'myapp/account/accounthome.html', {
    })
```

In previous **views**, I've used:

```
if user is not None and user.is_active
```

to check if a user is already authenticated or not when using native form classes like: `AuthenticationForm` for example when logging in a user.

But on this view I am not using that, is there someway to validate whether a user is logged in or not without using this `AuthenticationForm` class`again? This`view`s purpose is to show the homescreen when logged in, so it seems non-intuitive to extend that`AuthenticationForm` class again.

Any help or thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `is_authenticated()` method

Like this: `if request.user.is_authenticated():`

You can find the reference here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#methods

Comment: Is this the "best" method though? Doc says: "you should know this method returns True for any User instance"

Comment: Yes, it is the "best" one. The User instance represents the logged user, and when the user is not logged in - its representation is AnonymousUser instance.

Comment: Appreciate the explanation and answer. Thanks Alex